# How can I get the value by javascript,

Tags: javascript

I want to get the value of this div by javascript.

```
<div class = 'test'> 500 </div>
```

I tried this to get the 500 value, but it didnt work. Do you have some idea how can I get back 500?

```
values = document.getElementsByClassName("test").innerText
alert(values)
```

Comment: getElement**s**ByClassName - plural - therefore you're getting an array-like result even if it's only one `document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].innerText` - there's a big dupe on here though

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a list of elements, you have to be precise and say which element you want.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` selects first element.
`document.querySelector(".test")` means to select element that has class of "test"(class="test")

in real world cases you should use
`document.querySelectorAll(selector)`
and pick up element by index

example: `document.querySelectorAll(".test")[0]`

another example: `document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0]`

Note: Using `getElementsByClassName` is fine, but modern alternative to `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsById` is `querySelectorAll`

but for now this code would be fine:

```js
const value = document.querySelector(".test").textContent;
console.log(value);
```

```html
<div class='test'> 500 </div>
```

Comment: that does not explain anything

Comment: I've converted the code in your answer to a working snippet (and switched `alert` for `console.log`).  Remember to use snippets in future when posting JS\HTML answers as they make it easy to see the outcome

Comment: OP is not using querySelector*